# In React, does window.location.pathname work with extensions in the path?

Tags: reactjs, navigation

Beginner here.

I have a simple website that I am trying to build navigation for without using React Router. I was able to render a different body component on my main app.js file by using switch on window.location.pathname within an imported header component. I now want to go one layer deeper and have another layer of navigation within that newly rendered body component, but when I try to use the same method, both the navigation and the target element disappear. I do see the URL pathname update correctly, but for some reason the components don't want to render. What am I doing wrong?

```
import RMSPortfolioSlides from './RMSPortfolioSlides';
import CLPortfolioSlides from './CLPortfolioSlides';


const PortfolioMain = props => {

    let Current_slides
    switch (window.location.pathname) {
        case "/PortfolioMain":
        Current_slides = CLPortfolioSlides;
        break
        case "/PortfolioMain/Navigator":
        Current_slides = RMSPortfolioSlides
        break
        case "/PortfolioMain/CLSlideshow":
        Current_slides = CLPortfolioSlides
        break
    }

    return (<div className="portfolio_content">
<div className="current_slide_container">
<Current_slides /> 
</div>
<div className='portfolio_navigation'>
<nav className="portfolio_nav_container"><ul className="portfolio_list">
     <li>
      <a href="/PortfolioMain/Navigator" className="port_nav_link">RMS1</a> </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/PortfolioMain/CLSlideshow" className="port_nav_link">CL</a> </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/PortfolioMain/AverSlides" className="port_nav_link">AVER</a> </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/PortfolioMain/EnrollSlides" className="port_nav_link">E-REG</a> </li>
      <li>
      <a href="/PortfolioMain/MobileAppSlides" className="port_nav_link">MOBILE</a> </li>
        </ul> 
        </nav>
</div>
</div>
       
        );
    }
    
    export default PortfolioMain;
```

The component that renders PortfolioMain looks like this:

```
import './App.css';
import background from './img/portfoliobackground2.png';
import Header from './components/Header';
import PortfolioMain from './components/PortfolioMain';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Home from './components/Home';



function App() {
let component  
  switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case "/":
      component = <App  />
      break
      case"/Home":
      component = <Home  />
      break
      case"/PortfolioMain":
      component = <PortfolioMain />
      break
      case "/About":
      component = <About />
      break 
      case "/Contact":
      component = <Contact /> 
      break
  }
  
  return (

    <div 
    className="site_content" 
    style={{ 
      backgroundImage: `url(${background})`,
      backgroundSize:"cover", 
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>
     <div className="navigation_logo_container"><Header /></div>
     <div className="main_content">{component}</div>
    </div>
  
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: How have you set up the component that controls routing at the level above `<PortfolioMain>` (the one that renders `<PortfolioMain>`)?

Comment: I just added an edit to my post to include that main component as well, thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

The reason those elements (the navigation and target element) disappear is that the `<PortfolioMain>` component unmounts when on a subroute of "/PortfolioMain". This happens because you've defined the `<App>` component to only render `<PortfolioMain>` only when the pathname is *equal* to "/PortfolioMain", not just when the pathname starts with "/PortfolioMain".

The simplest fix for this would be to move from a `switch` statement to a `if`/`else if`/`else` statement and use `window.location.pathname.startsWith("/PortfolioMain")`. However I would recommend a more idiomatic approach that involves more changes but makes better use of React Router instead of the native browser routing API.

Check out the [Quick Start guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) for React Router V6 or [the V5 version](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for more information.

Instead of accessing `window.location.pathname` directly, you should use the abstractions provided by React Router. In this case, you'll need to use the components `<Switch>` and `<Route>` for V5, or `<Routes>` and `<Route>` for V6.

I'll show an example for V5 since the style more closely matches your current code setup, but you might want to update to V6 instead.

For V5, you'll want to use the `<Switch>` component instead of a `switch` statement and use the `<Route>` component to define routing details.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="site_content">
            <div className="navigation_logo_container"><Header /></div>
            <div className="site_content">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/Home">
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/PortfolioMain">
                        <PortfolioMain />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/About">
                        <About />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/Contact">
                        <Contact />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note I've removed the "/" route that renders the `<App>` component since that'll result in infinite recursion. You probably want the "/" route to render the `<Home>` component.

And for the `<PortfolioMain>` component:

```
function PortfolioMain() {
    return (
        <div className="portfolio_content">
            <div className="current_slide_container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/PortfolioMain">
                        <CLPortfolioSlides />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/PortfolioMain/Navigator">
                        <RMSPortfolioSlides />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/PortfolioMain/CLSlideshow">
                        <CLPortfolioSlides />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
            <div className='portfolio_navigation'>
                <nav className="portfolio_nav_container">
                    <ul className="portfolio_list">
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/PortfolioMain/Navigator" className="port_nav_link">RMS1</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/PortfolioMain/CLSlideshow" className="port_nav_link">CL</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/PortfolioMain/AverSlides" className="port_nav_link">AVER</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/PortfolioMain/EnrollSlides" className="port_nav_link">E-REG</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/PortfolioMain/MobileAppSlides" className="port_nav_link">MOBILE</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note the use of the `<Link>` component instead of `<a>` element, this will keep routing internal to your app (instead of making server requests on navigation).

Make sure your `<App>` component is rendered with a router component (e.g. `<BrowserRouter>`).

Again, if this is a new project, you'd be better off using React Router V6 since that's the newest version. The style of V6 is conceptually not very different but does require refactoring your components a bit so that they accept nested routing elements as children.